# Scaling custom pagination in a document-based Cocoa application

Tags: cocoa, printing, pagination, nsview

I am implementing printing in my document-based Cocoa application, and I'm wondering if anyone can help me out with this task.

I have to use a [custom pagination scheme](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Printing/Concepts/pagination.html) because the main view works in ways that normal pagination methods would not support. This works, however my view ends up being too big for the paper size most of the time. Tiling the view across multiple pages is not acceptable for my app, I would like to have my custom pagination work in the same way the NSFitPagination method works; if the view is too big for the page, it will resize the view by scaling it.

I thought I could do this by simply overriding the `drawRect:` method of my view and applying a transform to the current graphics context before it is drawn. However, it appears that printing mechanism calls the `drawRect:` method independently for each individual subview of a view that's being drawn, so applying a scale to the `drawRect:` of the superview doesn't work.

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this by instead of adding my view as a subview of the view to be printed, I overrode the drawRect method of the view being printed and manually set up a transformation and scaling and called drawRect on the view to print as a subview.